# Difference between the Kinect and PrimeSensor?

Tags: usb

I'm trying to determine if the Kinect or the [PrimeSensor](http://www.primesense.com/?p=487) is right for general purpose hobbyist work (X10 light control, relay activation, etc).

Does anyone know the difference?

Comment: What is your application?

Comment: @reemrevnivek Updated

Comment: Thanks!  Kellenjb offered a good answer on the relationship between the Kinect and PrimeSense, but I'm not sure I understand your application.  Perhaps it's because you have an idea that I can't come up with, but I'm not following how 3D imaging can be used with the X10 system and relay activation.  In any case, hobby projects that have to choose between the two will be better off with the Kinect because most of the hard work is done for you and it's readily available in single quantities.

Comment: @reemrevnivek I could see it being kind of cool to make some hand motion and then have lights dim as you lower your hands. Or something like that.

Comment: Yes, somthing like the "clapper" but by sign language.  It's also good for making a haloween "robot"; Check out the website "Kinect Hacks"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One difference is you probably can't get the Primesense unit unless you are a volume manufacturer. Hardware-wise, the Kinect includes an audio processor and tilt motor.
The performance of the depth sensor is likely to be the same.

Comment: What is the audio processor on the kinect do? I knew the primesense unit provides audio, I figured they were having the Xbox do the interpretation of the audio.

Answer (score 3):

PrimeSense is the company that developed Kinect hardware. The only difference is marketing and software. If you are wanting to develop a product for commercial use you will need to go through PrimeSense.

Edit:
For hobbyist work it will probably be easier to use a Kinect. There are already tons of people who have hacked it and there are now drivers public for the Kinect.

Comment: PrimeSense is the company, PrimeSensor is what happened in the first sentence of the question to make it more readable.  Fixed it for you.

Comment: Thanks!  I also found drivers from the Manufacturer themselves that works with the XBox Kinect http://openni.org/